# Need infopath to view "owner" when "folder" is selected

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, infopath-data-connections

I have a SharePoint team site list with two main columns, `FOLDER` and `OWNER`. Now I have created a form in InfoPath and people can select a `FOLDER` (drop down menu). Now I need the `OWNER` to be filled into the InfoPath form when the `FOLDER` item is selected.

So let's say my list is this:

FOLDER   | OWNER

C:\temp  | Santa

C:\win     | Dillweed

Now when people select `C:\temp` from the drop down, I want InfoPath to seek the corresponding owner, in this case, `Santa`. Now I want this to be presented in the InfoPath form.

How can we do it?

Answer (score 1):

Add a new receiving data connection with the list, e.g. *ReceivingData*. Set a default value for your control, which shall display the owner. As a default value you choose your owner column, but add a filter to it.

The filter should be something like: Main->Folder is equal to ReceivingData->Folder. Then it only shows the items you are selecting in the dropdown menu. *Main->* is your field in your current form and *ReceivingData->* works as a lookup to the items in your list.